# multithreading in java to print abc using 3 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

the task is to print abc repeatedly using three threads infinite number of times
my code is

```
package javap;

public class Pattern {

    volatile int status=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern p = new Pattern();

        A1 a=new A1(p);
        B1 b=new B1(p);
        C1 c=new C1(p);

        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
    }
}

class A1 extends Thread{
    Pattern p1;

    A1(Pattern p){
        this.p1 = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (p1) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    while(p1.status!=1){
                        p1.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.print("A ");
                    p1.status = 2;
                  p1.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 1 :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

class B1 extends Thread{

    Pattern p2;

    B1(Pattern p2){
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (p2) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    while(p2.status!=2){
                        p2.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.print("B ");
                    p2.status = 3;
                   p2.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 2 :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}


class C1 extends Thread{

    Pattern p3;

    C1(Pattern p){
        this.p3 = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            synchronized (p3) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    while(p3.status!=3){
                       p3.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.print("C ");
                    p3.status = 1;
                   p3.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 3 :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

when i tried using for(;;) or while(true) my ide hangs and i am nt getting any output
so i restricted it to 100 times.
is there anyway that i can make this run infinite number of times.

thanks in advance

Comment: `for (;; System.out.println()) Stream.of("a", "b", "c").parallel().forEachOrdered(System.out::print);`

Comment: should i repllace all the for loop with this @elliott frisch

Comment: That would replace everything you have written. It prints `"a"`, then `"b"`, then `"c"` in parallel (but ordered) - then it prints a newline and loops.

Comment: `System.out` is buffered. Call `System.out.flush();` after each (or after a number of) `System.out.print`'s and you should see the output. It will still likely bring your IDE to a very low speed if your output is going to the IDE's console - either add a newline in every so often to split the lines, or run it from the command line rather than from your IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your logic a little, and it is getting the output stream A B C with an interval of 1000 milliseconds (better for visualization).

```
public class Pattern {

    volatile int status = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern p = new Pattern();

        A1 a = new A1(p);
        B1 b = new B1(p);
        C1 c = new C1(p);

        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
    }
}

class A1 extends Thread {
    Pattern p1;

    A1(Pattern p) {
        this.p1 = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            synchronized (p1) {
                while (true) {
                    while (p1.status != 1) {
                        try {
                            p1.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("A ");
                    p1.status = 2;
                    p1.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 1 :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

class B1 extends Thread {

    Pattern p2;

    B1(Pattern p2) {
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            synchronized (p2) {
                while (true) {
                    while (p2.status != 2) {
                        try {
                            p2.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("B ");
                    p2.status = 3;
                    p2.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 2 :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

class C1 extends Thread {

    Pattern p3;

    C1(Pattern p) {
        this.p3 = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            synchronized (p3) {
                while (true) {
                    while (p3.status != 3) {
                        try {
                            p3.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("C ");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    p3.status = 1;
                    p3.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception 3 :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

> Output: A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C .....

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems fine.  That said, it seems you are writing too much code to achieve your goal... Consider using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3) to create your 3 threads and put them in a pool.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Then, Pass a task to the pool (A Callable)

```
Future<String> resultA = service.submit(() -> {
    System.out.print("A ");
    return "A";
});
```

Now wait for the task to finish before passing the next task:

```
resultA.get();
```

Here is a full code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 100) {
        service.submit(() -> {
            System.out.print("A ");
            return "A";
        }).get();

        service.submit(() -> {
            System.out.print("B ");
            return "B";
        }).get();

        service.submit(() -> {
            System.out.print("C ");
            return "C";
        }).get();

        x++;
    }

    service.shutdown();
}
```

That said you can remove all the Repeating code using:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 100) {
            service.submit(getTask("A ")).get();
            service.submit(getTask("B ")).get();
            service.submit(getTask("C ")).get();
            x++;
        }

        service.shutdown();
    }

    private static Callable<String> getTask(String task) {
        return () -> {
            System.out.print(task);
            return task;
        };
    }
}
```

note that main must not throw exceptions, but that should be obvious.

Also,  @Elliott Frisch answer is awesome as it uses JAVA 8 parallel streams.
 I think you are trying to learn about Threads so my answer uses the Executors API which Makes Thread related code much shorter and concise.

One should be familiar with both Streams and Executors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve above problem in below manner

```
public class BasePatternPrintExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Status lock = new Status(1);
        ThreadA t1 = new ThreadA("A", lock);
        ThreadB t2 = new ThreadB("B", lock);
        ThreadC t3 = new ThreadC("C", lock);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

}
```

Status Class

```
class Status{
    private int status;

    public Status(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

ThreadA

```
class ThreadA extends Thread {
    private Status lock;

    public ThreadA(String name, Status obj) {
        super(name);
        this.lock = obj;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    //System.out.println(lock.getStatus());
                    while(lock.getStatus() != 1){
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("A");
                    lock.setStatus(2);

                }
            }
    }
}
```

ThreadB

```
class ThreadB extends Thread {
    private Status lock;

    public ThreadB(String name, Status obj) {
        super(name);
        this.lock = obj;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    while(lock.getStatus() != 2){
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("B");
                    lock.setStatus(3);

                }
            }
    }
}
```

ThreadC

```
class ThreadC extends Thread {
    private Status lock;

    public ThreadC(String name, Status obj) {
        super(name);
        this.lock = obj;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    while(lock.getStatus() != 3){
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("C");
                    lock.setStatus(1);

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
 package threadexample;

class A extends Thread{
Pattern writeAbcExample;

public A(Pattern writeAbcExample) {

    this.writeAbcExample = writeAbcExample;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized(writeAbcExample){
            while(true){
                while(writeAbcExample.status!=1){
                    try{
                    writeAbcExample.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
                System.out.println("A ");
                Thread.sleep(400);
                writeAbcExample.status=2;
                writeAbcExample.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

}


class B extends Thread{
Pattern writeAbcExample;

public B(Pattern writeAbcExample) {

    this.writeAbcExample = writeAbcExample;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized(writeAbcExample){
            while(true){
                while(writeAbcExample.status!=2){
                    try{
                    writeAbcExample.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
                System.out.println("B ");
                Thread.sleep(400);
                writeAbcExample.status=3;
                writeAbcExample.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

 }


class C extends Thread{
Pattern writeAbcExample;

public C(Pattern writeAbcExample) {

    this.writeAbcExample = writeAbcExample;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized(writeAbcExample){
            while(true){
                while(writeAbcExample.status!=3){
                    try{
                    writeAbcExample.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
                System.out.println("C ");
                Thread.sleep(400);
                writeAbcExample.status=1;
                writeAbcExample.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

 }
 public class Pattern {
 volatile int status=1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern writeAbcExample=new Pattern();
    new A(writeAbcExample).start();
    new B(writeAbcExample).start();
    new C(writeAbcExample).start();
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PrintingABCUsingAtomicInteger {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(1);
            new Student(ai, 1, "A").start();
            new Student(ai, 2, "B").start();
            new Student(ai, 0, "C").start();
        }

    }

    class Student extends Thread {
        AtomicInteger ai;
        int b;
        String c;

        Student(AtomicInteger a, int b, String c) {
            this.ai = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (ai) {
                    int val = ai.intValue();
                    if (val >= 10) {
                        ai.notifyAll();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (val % 3 == b) {
                            System.out.println(" Thread " + b + " printing value " + c);
                            ai.getAndIncrement();
                            ai.notifyAll();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                ai.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
 Thread 1 printing value A
 Thread 2 printing value B
 Thread 0 printing value C
 Thread 1 printing value A
 Thread 2 printing value B
 Thread 0 printing value C
 Thread 1 printing value A
 Thread 2 printing value B
 Thread 0 printing value C
```